# No of ways to form a team of surgeon and assistants underconditions.

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

> There are $40$ doctors in surgical department of the 
>   AIIMS .In how many ways can they be arranged to
>   form a team with $1$ surgeon and $4$ assistants ?

$\color{green}{a.)\ 40 \times \dbinom{39}{4} }\\
b.)\ 41 \times \dbinom{39}{4} \\
c.)\ 41 \times \dbinom{40}{4} \\
d.)\ \text{none of these} $

I did $\dbinom{40}{1} \times \dbinom{39}{4} \times 5!$.

But the answer given in book is $a.)$

I look for a short and simple way .

I have studied maths up to $12$th grade.

Comment: What is your reasoning for 5! ?

Comment: $5!$ is doing permutations .of  $5$ people

Comment: You don't need that. The order of the team members does not matter.

Comment: Example, $abcde$ and $bacde $ makes a difference as $a$ is surgeon if former and $b$ in later.

Answer (score 3):

There are $40$ ways to choose the doctor; think of this as being the first location in the list. Then there are $\binom{39}{4}$ ways to choose the remaining $4$ assistants; think of them as being the remaining four locations. So the answer is $40\cdot \binom{39}{4}$. No need for the extra $5!$.